# how can I render multiple charts in chartjs?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

These are the data that I have to render using chartjs in react. I made a custom component for rednering the charts, It's working properly for single line charts can't just render multiline charats here.

This is my Chartjs Custom component

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import Chart from "chart.js";

const ChartComponent = ({ data, label, min, max }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvasObj = canvasRef.current;
        const context = canvasObj.getContext("2d");

        new Chart(context, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: label,
                        backgroundColor: "transparent",
                        data: data,
                    },
                ],
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            type: "time",
                            distribution: "linear",
                            time: {
                                unit: "month",
                                displayFormats: {
                                    quarter: "YYYY mm dd",
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                suggestedMax: max,
                                suggestedMin: min,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        });
    }, [data, label, min, max]);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef}> </canvas>;
};

export default ChartComponent;
```

and these are the data that I want to render on the chart, each array has to be line on the chart.
"dare" array is going to be my xAxes and other columns are going to be my yAxes

```js
const date = [
1370,
1371,
1372,
1373,
1374,
1375,
1376,
1377,
1378,
1379,
1380,
1381,
1382,
1383,
1384,
1385,
1386,
1387,
1388,
1389,
1390,
1391,
1392,
1393,
1394,
1395,
1396,
1397,
1398,
1399,
]

const level = [
1275.77,
1274.73,
1273.83,
1273.41,
1273.65,
1273.5,
1273.28,
1272.83,
12732.83,
1271.6,
1271.6,
1271.36,
1271.01,
1270.67,
1270.4,
1270.15,
1270.08,
1270.54,
1270.32,
1270.27,
1271.3,
1271.27,
]

const area = [
4753.37,
5039.93,
5391.36,
5723.07,
5724.38,
5724.38,
5643.3,
5498.31,
4978.31,
4544.5,
4215.19,
4070.4,
4148.57,
4099.62,
4028.18,
3794.98,
3794.98,
3436.8,
3029.65,
2869.53,
2583.24,
2196.58,
1880.42,
1525.59,
1404.46,
2047.49,
1783.47,
1722.87,
2828.37,
2807.79,
]

const volume = [
21010,
22150,
26910,
30710,
30770,
30770,
29010,
27990,
21500,
16540,
12580,
10840,
11830,
11210,
10310,
8550,
8550,
6120,
4320,
3610,
2640,
1840,
1290,
860,
750,
1560,
1140,
1050,
3430,
3350,
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is called rendering multiple datasets, to do that you should put the `date` inside `labels` array and the other arrays of data inside `datasets` array each in a separate object.
I tried to implement an example using your data is a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-forked-flj74
you can just reformat the dates to your needs